# Do you ever use protected visibility in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, private, public, protected

Confession: I only use **private** and **public** visibility for my methods!

I have a feeling this is a bad thing. But in Rails it just doesn't seem to come up as an issue.

Does anyone have an example in Rails where it would be a big mistake not to use **protected** visibility?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Update** -- Please see the comment below that links to a [true explanation of `protected`/`private` in Ruby](http://weblog.jamisbuck.org/2007/2/23/method-visibility-in-ruby).  That was a deep seated prejudice left over from my Java days, indeed.  The only important part left to my answer is that controller methods that are not actions should not be `public` (or at least your routes should protect them).

Single Table Inheritance is a perfect example of when `protected` is helpful in the model tier, as it's one of the most common uses of inheritance there.

In the controller tier, helper methods defined on `ApplicationController` should be marked as `protected` -- if they were `private` the other controllers would not be able to access them, but if they are `public` Rails will treat them as actions.

Personally, I find that I use class inheritance more than many of my friends and coworkers, even in Rails applications.  Because I use it often (and coming out of my Java days), I favor `protected` for all helper methods to give freedom to anyone (usually myself) who wants to extend the class -- unless I'm really really embarrassed about one, then I mark it `private`.  :)

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. (Not sure what STI is though).

Comment: "helper methods defined on ApplicationController should be marked as protected -- if they were private the other controllers would not be able to access them" -- fyi, this is incorrect.  See example here:  http://pastie.org/842898 .  Protected/private in Ruby is about 'self' and receivers, not inheritance.  "Note that, unlike languages such as Java, inheritance plays absolutely no part in determining method visibility in Ruby." -- http://weblog.jamisbuck.org/2007/2/23/method-visibility-in-ruby

Answer (score 0):

I have SingleTableInheritance

class Person < AR::base
class Teacher < Person
calss Student < Person

And I use the protected methods to implement a private method that is common for Student and Teacher:

```
class Person < AR::base
  def self.find(*args)
    reject_leaves(super(*args))
  end
protected
  def self.reject_leaves(target) #like a private in Teacher and Student
    case target
      when Array target.select{|t| reject_leaves(t)}
      when Person (target.leave_date < Date.today ? target : nil)
      else target
    end
  end
end
```

Disclaimer: There are plugins like act-as-paranoid and other to implement the feature I use here to show you the case but I have a more complex landscape, that I have simplified here to get to your point.

Comment: fyi, your example above doesn't work correctly -- you can call `Person.reject_leaves(...)` without a problem.  'public/protected/private' in ruby are not keywords -- they are method invocations on `self` that modify the state of `self`.  Since you change what `self` is when you do `def self. reject_leaves` you no longer have the `protected` state set up.  to get what you want you'd need something like the second example (`Prot2`) here:  http://pastie.org/842952